# Assets on appearing in storyboard selection dropdown

Tags: xcode

I'm making a tab bar view controller, and I'm setting up the images for the selected and unselected image. However, the newly imported assets aren't showing up for me to use as the selected and unselected image. I have confirmed they are in the asset catalog. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Clean build folder, quit xcode, restart xcode, clean build folder again. Should do the trick